# How to get tikzexternalize to typeout the current figure name for use by latexmk?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, latexmk

I am trying to patch tikz-externalize to do a `\typeout{figure-0.pdf}`(described [here](https://www.mankier.com/1/latexmk#Custom_Dependencies)) for all figures, so `latexmk` realizes it is a dependency and runs the following rule

```perl
add_cus_dep('md5', 'pdf', 0, 'gnu_make');
sub gnu_make {
    system("$make -f  %A.makefile \"$_[0].pdf\"");
}
```

but I can't find how the next file is named and where it is done.

Edit: another question doing something similiar[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330977/latexmk-file-not-found-even-though-custom-dependency-should-add-it), did same thing, but build their own environment, while I would like to patch an existing environment ( the internal externalize environment)

Comment: What's a dependency of what? `/tikz/external/figure list=true` (which it is initially) will create a file with all the figure names. Is that what you are looking for? Or maybe `\tikzpicturedependsonfile`?

Comment: @schtandard `\tikzpicturedependsonfile` is used for other files and I am trying to get the entries of `file.figurelist` to be written  to the log file with an `.pdf` extension at the same time; if this works `latexmk` should realize the file depends on them and run the appropriate make file